# Environment and species a century after a nuclear war

Tags: biology, post-apocalypse, nuclear

What would the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone imply for a global-scale nuclear event, including environment and wildlife (including mutation, survival, and migration), specifically in the Washington DC area? The timespan is 100 years after the nuclear event.

Comment: I like the idea of breaking up the setting and remolding it for realism of world building, but there are simply too many questions going on here. You should limit down the scope.

Comment: And before somebody suggests it, *no, this question would not fit on Sci-Fi Stack Exchange.*

Comment: You should simply use the Fallout setting is you want to write Fallout fanfic. Fallout has many things that are unrealsitic and don't hold up under scrutiny. The games are still fun, tho.

Comment: I agree with Polygnome, part of the idea of fanfics is to set a story in the same universe. That said, this is too broad simply because you are asking far too many questions at once. Narrow it down to one that you'd like answered first, flesh it out a bit (I really doubt everyone is familiar with the Fallout universe -- I'm not, for one -- so explaining the relevant bits would be a good start), then take what you learn from the answers to that and apply it to the next, asking about any parts of it you still can't figure out. Compare http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3825/29.

Comment: I also recommend reviewing [Are questions based on movies okay?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3141/29) and [Are answers solely referencing novels/movies/etc. okay?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1731/29). While the latter is about answers more than questions, the same general principles apply. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in our site's [help].

Comment: In keeping with Polygnome and MichaelKjorling's definitions of fanfic, you really shouldn't modify any canon from the original source which in this case is the (video?) game.  However, as an author you have complete control over which parts you stress and which parts you hide by omission.  If you don't like vacuum tube robots, then don't mention the vacuum tubes.  Don't offer any alternatives (like transistors) but instead just fail to describe how the robot works.  It is just a robot (which is part of canon).  Let your readers add or omit the antique tech as they wish.

Comment: @CharlotteWolery I modified the wording of your question. Feel free to revert my changes if they change your intention for the question. Based on the changes you made, I'm voting to reopen.